# How to get the value of the selected date from bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker to choose the date.

This is my html code

```
 <div>

<input  type="text" name="From" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-click="open($event)"  ng-model="Filters.Date" is-open="opened"  datepicker-options="dateOptions"  ng-required="true" close-text="X" />

</div>
```

I have written a function to display previous day date by default. But I am not able to get the selected date. Some default value like "1433077321717" is displayed if I get the selected date value

How can I get the selected date from the date picker?

Comment: check this : https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#getdate

Comment: its the timestamp you are getting new Date(1433077321717) = Sun, 31 May 2015 13:02:01 GMT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix time stamp is in seconds. You can convert it into milliseconds (by multiplying it by 1000) and passing it to the date constructor like this to convert it to a Date object.

```
var unixtimestamp=1433077321717;
var selected=new Date(unixtimestamp*1000);
```

Comment: i think it is already in milliseconds multiplying it with 1000 makes it worse

Answer (score 2):

The default value which you are getting is the timestamp in milliseconds. Use date filter which are provided in angularjs.

{{timestamp | date: 'short'}}. You can follow the following link for transforming the timestamp in the other formats :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: I believe this is more angularjs friendly solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think Bootstrap is returning the time stamp.

From your inputs.

you have written a function to select the previous day. for today(1st JUN 2015) it will be 31st MAY 2015.

The output you got is a timestamp
new Date(timestamp) i.e new Date(1433077321717) = Sun May 31 2015 18:32:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) i.e nothing but the day you have set.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var date = $filter('date')($scope.Filters.Date, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

but first add $filter to your controller

```
app.controller('Test',  function($scope, $filter,...){
}
```